# Recursive search doesnt stop in 2D, does wrong movements

Tags: multidimensional-array

My recursive method doesnt correctly find a few words.
Words found are marked, those that unmarked form a word.

How can the research fonction only look for words in straight lines or fix the research.

```
        bool answer = trouverMot(tab, bankMots, x - 1, y, (longueurMatch + 1), motNumero, positions1) ||
                      trouverMot(tab, bankMots, x + 1, y, (longueurMatch + 1), motNumero, positions1) ||
                      trouverMot(tab, bankMots, x, y - 1, (longueurMatch + 1), motNumero, positions1) ||
                      trouverMot(tab, bankMots, x, y + 1, (longueurMatch + 1), motNumero, positions1);
```

Comment: 9  c  E  k  i  e  e  g  _a_  D  n  a  q  
 10  c  Y  e  t  a  _h_  _c_  _r_  A  i  m  u <- What's wrong with this? Is it that there are two _arch_ words? Then wouldn't the probe order matter?

Comment: So you *don't* want the word to change direction. Instead of trying all directions, have you tried an extra parameter in `trouverMot`, `enum dir { N, E, S, O }`? It would probably reduce your search-space, too.

Comment: @Neil Well once it finds a pattern Id like it to move in that direction, Ive been trying to implement your idea without success. How could I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to constrain the system to only search one way, you need to have more information in the recursive function `trouverMot`, constraining the direction. To do this, I recommend an `enum`, something like,

```
enum dir { N, E, S, O };
```

The added parameter might look like,

```
static bool trouverMot(char tab[150][45], char bankMots[13][13], int x, int y, int longueurMatch, int motNumero, positions positions1, const enum dir dir)
```

This reduces the branching factor from 4 to 1.

```
switch(dir) {
case N: answer = trouverMot(tab, bankMots, x, y - 1,
    (longueurMatch + 1), motNumero, positions1, N); break;
case E: answer = trouverMot(tab, bankMots, x + 1, y,
    (longueurMatch + 1), motNumero, positions1, E); break;
case S: answer = trouverMot(tab, bankMots, x, y + 1,
    (longueurMatch + 1), motNumero, positions1, S); break;
case O: answer = trouverMot(tab, bankMots, x - 1, y,
    (longueurMatch + 1), motNumero, positions1, O); break;
}
```

However, in `trouverPremierLettre`, one needs to check all four directions.

```
if(trouverMot(tab, bankMots, nligne, ncol, longueurMatch, w, positions1, N)
    || trouverMot(tab, bankMots, nligne, ncol, longueurMatch, w, positions1, E)
    || trouverMot(tab, bankMots, nligne, ncol, longueurMatch, w, positions1, S)
    || trouverMot(tab, bankMots, nligne, ncol, longueurMatch, w, positions1, O))
```